# TYPO3 Fluid: How to pass several domain objects to the action controller

Tags: typo3, fluid

I want to have a big Fluid form where multiple records can be modified at once. There is only one form on the page to submit all records.

```
<f:if condition="{records}">
<f:then>
    <f:form action="update" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="updateRecords" object="{records}">
    <div class="row">
        <f:for each="{records}" as="element" iteration="recordsIterator">
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <h5>{element.title}</h5>
            <div>
                <f:if condition="{feature}">
                    <f:then>
                        <h6>
                            <f:translate key="records.feature" />
                        </h6>
                        <f:form.checkbox property="feature" value="2" />
                        <label for="tx_example_records[updateRecords][{recordsIterator.index}][feature]">
                            <f:translate key="records.read" />
                        </label>
                    </f:then>
                </f:if>
                </div>
            </div>
        </f:for>
    </div>
    <f:form.submit class="button" value="{f:translate(key: 'submit', default: '[submit]')}"><input class="button" type="submit" name="" value="Submit" /></f:form.submit>
    </f:form>
</f:if>
```

The corresponding controller has only a domain object as parameter.

```
/**
 * action update
 *
 * @param \Foo\Example\Domain\Model\Records $updateRecords
 * @return void
 */
public function updateAction(\Foo\Example\Domain\Model\Records $updateRecords) : void
```

However I need a solution with an array of all listed `Domain\Model\Records` passed as a parameter from the submitted form to the `updateAction`. The attribute `feature` is a checkbox to be checked if the record's value of feature `= '2';` .  Is this somehow possible in TYPO3? Or must I use some tricks to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with a Data Transfer Object here, holding the values you need to submit the form. You can find some general information related to Extbase here: https://usetypo3.com/dtos-in-extbase.html